# Gradle 2.0 generates ivy.xml seemingly by default

Tags: java, gradle, ivy

I currently trying out gradle and am using the java plugin.
However every time I build, I find that the ivy.xml is getting generated as well. 
I have not included any other plugin such as the 'ivy-publish' or any other.
Is this gradle's default behaviour?
I can simply ignore it but I was curious regarding why.

Edit: 10Aug2014

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Quickstart', 'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

sourceSets {
    mainTwo {
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
       flatDir {
           dirs 'dist-two'
       }
    }
}

task all (dependsOn : [uploadArchives,jar])  { 
    println 'Done!'
}


task hello << {
    println 'Hello Earth'
}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of Gradle generating an ivy.xml by default. Please provide more details such as what exact command you are running, where you see the ivy.xml being generated, relevant details of your build script, etc.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I am overriding the sourceSet for the java plugin. Could this be a reason? I will be editing the question with the gradle script.

Comment: Same for me @RavindraHV. I don't have the `sourceSets` in my build file and the unecessary `ivy.xml` is being generated when I run `gradle uploadArchives` to copy the jar to a local dir.